# GdataXML (Ray Wenderlich's iPhone RSS Reader Tutorial)

Tags: ios, rss, gdata, gdataxml

I'm following [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial) on creating a Simple RSS feed app.
Its great so far but I've found an issue.

At the point where he tells you to download GDataXML, he gives you a link that seems to not work, or have the desired libraries.

This is a screenshot of the portion of the tutorial:

[Image Hosted by ImageShack.us http://imageshack.us/a/img35/8381/screenshot20130416at541.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img35/8381/screenshot20130416at541.png)

This the screenshot of the page the link takes you to:

[Image Hosted by ImageShack.us http://imageshack.us/a/img9/6524/screenshot20130416at542.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img9/6524/screenshot20130416at542.png)

I really don't know what to do. The zip file on that link is for some addon for calenders.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the [Source](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/checkout) tab/link, you will be shown a page with the location of the read-only source. The location of the read-only source is displayed on that page:

```
# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gdata-objectivec-client-read-only
```

Comment: If you go up a directory level to the trunk, that works: http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/